# JSON.parse error upon returning PartialView from controller

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { occupants: occupants },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#summaryContent").html(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

And a controller that looks like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Verification(List<OccupantDto> occupants)
    {
        //do stuff
        return PartialView();
    }
```

And I'm getting this error in my ajax call

```
Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:5
```

I tried removing `dataType: "json"` from my ajax call, that removes the error, and it renders my partial view, however, in my controller, `occupants` is an empty list. Adding `dataType: "json"` populates `occupants` in my controller, but throws me an error.

Comment: Which line code gives the error?

Comment: console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); in the javascript

Comment: Answer below by Shyju tells you why you are getting the error and how can you remove it. Now to understand why you are getting empty list when you remove datatype can you share the code which populates occupants variable in JavaScript? You can try doing JSON.Stringify to occupants variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part in your `$.ajax` method call

```
dataType: "json",
```

tells jQuery that you are expecting the result from server as a valid  json string. So jQuery will try to explicitly parse it to a js object (*using `JSON.parse()` method*) with the assumption that it is a valid JSON  string response came back because ***you assured jQuery*** that using the `dataType: "json"` option.

But in your case you are returning a view result, which is just HTML markup. So it cannot be parsed to a javascript object. `JSON.parse()` will throw a SyntaxError exception if the string to parse is not valid JSON. That is what you are getting because the parse method call crashed, hence it executes the `error` handler of your `$.ajax` method.

Simply remove that line which specifies the `dataType` line. This should work

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { occupants: occupants },
}).done(function (data) {
    $("#summaryContent").html(data);
}).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
    console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
});
```

**In most of the cases, you do not need to necessarily specify the `dataType` property value**. If nothing is specified jQuery will try to infer it based on the mime type of the response coming back.

Now, As long as you have a valid array of items (matching with the structure of `OccupantDto`), Your `occupants` parameter will be properly mapped by model binder and will not be null/empty collection.

Assuming `OccupantDto` has an `Id` and `Name` property (which is **set**table public properties), This should work

```
var occupants = [{ name: "Scott",id:4},{ name: "Shyju",id:6}];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Verification")',
    data: { occupants: occupants }
})
```

As of jQuery 3.0, the `success()`, `error()` and `complete()` callbacks are removed . You may use `done()`, `fail()`, and `always()` instead.